# ASP.NET Core Disable CORS for specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

I have different set of controllers in my application (let's say A and B). CORS for A controller needs to be enabled and disabled for B controllers.
I have configured CORS via the policies in the following way:

ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddCors(
    options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "AllowCors",
            builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().WithMethods(
                        HttpMethod.Get.Method,
                        HttpMethod.Put.Method,
                        HttpMethod.Post.Method,
                        HttpMethod.Delete.Method).AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("CustomHeader");
                });
    });
services.AddMvcCore()
```

Configure method

```
app.UseCors("AllowCors");
app.UseMvc();
```

Set of A controllers has EnableCors attribute

```
[EnableCors("AllowCors")]
public class ControllerA1: Controller
```

CORS works for set of A controller as expected (tested via the browser). However, it also does work for B controllers! I even tried to disable CORS with DisableCors attribute explicitly:

```
[DisableCors]
public class ControllerB1: Controller
```

However, ControllerB1 controller can be requested from UI anyway.

Headers in browser for B1 contoller

Request

```
Provisional headers are shown
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Referer: http://localhost:5000/all
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit Chrome/69 Safari/537
```

Response

```
Request URL: http://XX.XX.XX.XX/getall
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: XX.XX.XX.XX:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: CustomCount        
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
```

Could you please advise how to disable CORS for specific controllers?

Comment: How are you testing this, on the same machine?

Comment: It is tested on different machines, UI is localhost and API is deployed on a remote server. I have added request / response headers in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you've done two things of note in setting up the WebHost:

1. Created a custom CORS policy named `AllowCors`.
2. Added the CORS middleware to the pipeline, which uses `AllowCors` as its `policyName`.

Here's a snippet of the `Invoke` function that gets called for the CORS middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(CorsConstants.Origin))
    {
        var corsPolicy = _policy ?? await _corsPolicyProvider?.GetPolicyAsync(context, _corsPolicyName);
        if (corsPolicy != null)
        {
            var corsResult = _corsService.EvaluatePolicy(context, corsPolicy);
            _corsService.ApplyResult(corsResult, context.Response);

    ...
```

In this snippet, `_policy` is `null` and `_corsPolicyName` is `AllowCors`. Because `AllowCors` is the name of a valid policy that was added using `AddCors`, this results in the CORS middleware applying the revelant CORS headers for *all requests*.

In your example, you've also used both `[EnableCors(...)]` and `[DisableCors]`, which are MVC authorisation filters. By doing this, you're mostly just telling MVC to take care of CORS, which is *independent* of the CORS middleware you've added to the WebHost's pipeline.

This combination of MVC and CORS middleware is what is causing your unexpected results. The middleware is adding the CORS headers to your request *regardless* of whether or not you're asking it not to by using the `[DisableCors]` attribute - the CORS middleware has no idea that this MVC concept (a filter) even exists.

Based on this information, you can fix your issue in one of two ways:

1. Remove the `policyName` parameter from your call to `UseCors`.
2. Remove the `UseCors` call itself.

With option 1, the `UseCors` middleware will use the default policy, if it's been configured using `AddDefaultPolicy` on the `CorsOptions` passed into the `AddCors` delegate.

With option 2, the CORS middleware is simply excluded from the pipeline. This will also work in your example, because you've used `[EnableCors(...)]` where you need it. This also means that you don't need to use `[DisableCors]` at all - it'll default to not adding the CORS headers.

This raises the question: When *would* `[DisableCors]` be useful? As an example, consider the following basic controller:

```
[EnableCors("AllowCors")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Action1() =>
        ...

    public IActionResult Action2() =>
        ...
}
```

It's clear that in this example, both `Action1` and `Action2` will set the CORS headers. If you *didn't* want `Action2` to set the headers, you could annotate it with `[DisableCors]`.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the app.useCors is important

```
//...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("customPolicy");
app.UseEndpoints(...)
//...
```