# cant access to token because of CORS policy in .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, jwt

i'm new in Angular
i created a JWT authentication service in in .Net Core and i want to consume it in my application,my front end looks like this:

Its my service:

```
              constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
          getPosts(x){  

            // return  this.http.post(this.url,{params:{username:x}});
            return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:44361/api/Auth/token/', { x })
         .pipe(map(user => {
         // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
         if (user ) {
         // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
         localStorage.setItem('TokenInfo', JSON.stringify(user));
         }

         return user;
         }));

                 }
```

here is my login component:

```
            data:any;
          constructor(
            private router: Router, 
            private authService: MyserviceService) { }

          signIn(x) {

        console.log(x);

            this.authService.getPosts(x)
            .subscribe(response => {
              let token = (<any>response).token;
              localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
              console.log(token);
              this.invalidLogin = false;
              this.router.navigate(["/"]);
            }, err => {
              this.invalidLogin = true;
            });
          }
        }
```

Its very strange why i cant log it,i generate it in Postman but here in my application every time i get 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44361/api/Auth/token/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource,even thought CORS is enabled in my application and followed the instruction of microsoft doc,here is my back end in .Net core

My Configuration service:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        //services.AddCors();

        string securityKey = "My_First_Key_generated_by_myself";
        var semetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
            {

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "morteza",
                    ValidAudience = "pass",
                    IssuerSigningKey = semetricSecurityKey


                };
            }

            );

        // services.AddCors();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
              "CorsPolicy",
              builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

my Configuration:

```
          public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {   
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseHsts();
                }
               app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");       
                app.UseMvc();
            }
        }
```

My Auth controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetToken(string username)
    {
        //  return Ok("hi Morteza");
        if (username == "morteza") { 
        string securityKey = "My_First_Key_generated_by_myself";
        var semetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));


        var signIncredentials = new SigningCredentials(semetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "http://localhost:4200/",
            audience:  "https://localhost:44361/api/Auth/token/",
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
            claims: claims,
            signingCredentials: signIncredentials);
        return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534167/asp-net-core-disable-cors-for-specific-controllers

Comment: @JacopoSciampi you mean the problem is with my back end?

Comment: CORS it totally a BE stuff.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi should i post my back end part here to see if the problem comes from there?its 2 days im wasting my time to find a solution

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Now's better. I sugget you to change the title in something including the word "CORS" so other people can help you out. I'm not a BE developer

Comment: try this line `builder => builder.WithOrigins("*")` instead of `builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`.

Comment: @G.Dimov i tried that and still get the same error ,CORS issue